# How to detect screen change in immersive mode on Android

Tags: android, screen, detect, accessibilityservice

I am creating an app that monitors screen changes and set to the immersive mode or normal mode. I use `accessibilityservice` `TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED`. It works except when a user clicks recent apps in immersive sticky mode.

In immersive mode, it doesn't fire an event when change app from recent apps.
How can I detect screen changes in immersive mode using `accessibilityservice`?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"` inside your xml file for accessibility services